# PHP AJAX script not working properly on all conditions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script where I want to process form data using ajax. The script is returning the success message but not the error message. Have a look at the scripts below.

AJAX Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            flip: $("#flip").val(),
            amount: $("#amount").val()
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url: "flip-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
                $("#submit").hide();
                $("#loading").show();
                $(".message").hide();
      },
            success: function(json){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
                    $('#mywallet').html('$' + json.deduct);
                    $("#submit").show();
                    $("#loading").hide();
                },3000);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

PHP Script

```
<?php
session_start();
include'config/db.php';
$msg = null;
$sessionid = (!empty($_SESSION['login']))?$_SESSION['login']:null;

$wp = $pdo->prepare("SELECT set_cointoss_wp, set_cointoss_prob FROM settings");
$wp-> execute();
$sp = $wp->fetch();
    $percent = $sp['set_cointoss_wp'];
    $probablity = $sp['set_cointoss_prob'];

$bal = $pdo->prepare("SELECT mb_acbal, mb_wallet FROM mem_balance WHERE mb_id = :mem");
$bal-> bindValue(':mem', $sessionid);
$bal-> execute();
$bf = $bal->fetch();
    $balance = $bf['mb_acbal'];
    $wallet = $bf['mb_wallet'];

$coin   = (!empty($_POST['flip']))?$_POST['flip']:null;
$amount = (!empty($_POST['amount']))?$_POST['amount']:null;

if($_POST){
        if($wallet < $amount){
            $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Sorry buddy! You have insufficient balance. Please <a href=''>recharge</a> your wallet.</div>";
        }else{
            $deduct = $wallet-$amount;
            $prob = rand(1, 10);

            //set new wallet balance after bet amount deduction
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE mem_balance SET mb_wallet = :bal WHERE mb_user = :user");
            $stmt-> bindValue(':bal', $deduct);
            $stmt-> bindValue(':user', $sessionid);
            $stmt-> execute();

        if($coin == ''){
          $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Sorry buddy! Fields cannot be left empty.</div>";
        }else{
          if($coin == "head"){
                    if($prob <= $probablity){
                        $result = 1;
                    }else{
                      $result = 2;
                    }
            if($result == 1){
              // win
                        $wa = $amount*$percent;
                        $win_amount = $wa/100;
                        $final_cash = $win_amount+$balance;

                        // update database with winning amount
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE mem_balance SET mb_acbal = :bal WHERE mb_user = :user");
                        $stmt-> bindValue(':bal', $final_cash);
                        $stmt-> bindValue(':user', $sessionid);
                        $stmt-> execute();

              $msg = "<div class='message-success'>Congratulations buddy! You won... <strong>$".$win_amount."</strong> has been credited to your account.</div>";
            }else{
              // loose
              $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Sorry buddy! You lost... But do not loose hope. Try your luck again :)</div>";
            }
          }else{
                    if($prob <= $probablity){
                        $result = 2;
                    }else{
                      $result = 1;
                    }
            if($result == 1){
              // loose
              $msg = "<div class='message-error'>Sorry buddy! You lost... But do not loose hope. Try your luck again :)</div>";
            }else{
              // win
                        $wa = $amount*$percent;
                        $win_amount = $wa/100;
                        $final_cash = $win_amount+$balance;

                        // update database with winning amount
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE mem_balance SET mb_acbal = :bal WHERE mb_user = :user");
                        $stmt-> bindValue(':bal', $final_cash);
                        $stmt-> bindValue(':user', $sessionid);
                        $stmt-> execute();

              $msg = "<div class='message-success'>Congratulations buddy! You won... <strong>$".$win_amount."</strong> has been credited to your account.</div>";
            }
          }
        }
        }
        echo json_encode(array('status' => $msg, 'deduct' => $deduct));
}
?>
```

Here in the scripts above, when `if($wallet < $amount)` condition is false and `else` condition is executed, the scripts works fine and returns `<div class='message-success'>` as required. But, if `if($wallet < $amount)` condition is true then its not returning `<div class='message-error'>` and the loading image keeps on moving (as if waiting for the response) but does not receives any response in return. I am stuck since a few days on this but not being able to find any solution for the same. Please help.

Comment: Consider cleaning up your code. You have at least 5 nested if statements which is terrible for readability, maintainability and just about anything else to do with coding. It looks like you *might* be missing a closing brace before `if($coin == ''){` statement as well, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but I think in your php script **$deduct** has been declared inside the else block.

so when the script executes and **if ($wallet < $amount)** condition evaluates to true, then the else part is skipped and you directly return this:-

```
return  echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => $msg,
        'deduct' => $deduct
    ));
```

so it might be the case that $deduct is not recognized. try executing by declaring the **$deduct** before the if block.

Comment: you did not get my question properly.. read again.. you are just saying reverse of what my problem is.. when `if ($wallet < $amount` condition is true, the $msg inside it should be displayed but when it is true json is not returning the msg...

Comment: You have declared the variable `$deduct` inside the else part, so when `if ($wallet < $amount)` is `true`, `$deduct` is an unknown variable for `json_encode()`. You should try adding `$deduct = 0` before your `if($wallet < $amount)`.

Comment: now you cracked it dude... but instead of declaring `$deduct = 0` I just shifted `$deduct = $wallet-$amount;` before the if statement.. now its working perfect.. this made me stuck for hell 2 days... thanks buddy..

Comment: Happy to help :)